# Interpret GARCH

Tags: references, interpretation, garch

is anyone know how to interpret GARCH model? I mean, maybe giving me some recommendations for books or research papers that contain an interpretation of GARCH in it? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enders' textbook on Applied Econometric Time Series offers a pretty comprehensive yet accessible coverage of ARCH/GARCH models (see Ch 3): https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Applied+Econometric+Time+Series%2C+4th+Edition-p-9781118808566